# There's a way to remove a property to a sdt if your value is null?

Tags: json, genexus

I have one SDT that i use to make a http request to a external api.

My problem is that i don't have send from the external api the price if the model initialize with "A".

**ProductUpdateRequestSDT**

```
model
price
status
manufacturer_id
price_attacked
cost_price
weight
length
```

So i make this way:

```
&ProductUpdateRequest = new()
&ProductUpdateRequest.model = &PRODUTOCodigo
```

This `PRODUTOCodigo` initialize with the letter **"A"**, so i don't have to send to my external api the key `"price"`.

If i don't attaches a value in my variable `"price"`, anyway my SDT sends to the api the key `"price"`.

But sometimes my model don't start with the letter **"A"** and i have to pass a value to price.

I do not want create more than one sdt without the price property because there other rules that i don't have to pass one key.

So, i need to remove a property to my SDT after the `new()` depending of the other properties.

This is possible in genexus?

Answer (score 1):

Check the SDT element property Json Null Serialization with value No Property
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?36980,Json+Null+Serialization+property

Comment: I'm using genexus 15 and in the Json Information options just have Json name. I can find this option in genexus 16, but i can't upgrade this project to gx 16. There's other way to do this?